# How to regroup some old commits on master?

Tags: merge, gitlab, squash

On my GitLab repo every merge request is integrated as a single commit. However one day it failed partially due to a GitLab UI bug (if you merge in the UI with the squash option checked it will not squash if the squash option was not checked at the opening of the merge request).

Is there a way I could squash these commits in retrospect?

Comment: Have you considered an interactive rebase? You'll have to force push to master, though.

Comment: I have tried it in the base and retry today but i got some errors. "Could not apply XXX... Commit message". This error occured at the second commit among 54. The command i used was git rebase -i HEAD~54
, then i modify around 20 pick into f for the desired commits.

Comment: It's very difficult to guess what the problem is. Give a [mcve].

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it on a new repository even doing few merges before among the commit. I guess that my repo history is too complicated or I don't know...